# How do I insert values from many textboxes into my database with minimal code?

Tags: c#, sql

Please kindly bear with me. I need to insert the values from a lot of textboxes and combo-boxes into a DB. Now, if any of the textboxes or combo-boxes is EMPTY, I want that to be skipped, i.e. the previous value in the DB, if any, should be left untouched. Something like updating a profile. I will be so glad if you can come to my rescue.

I don't want to be writing endless 
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues(...);
   ...

Thank you in anticipation.

Edit:
I want a situation, for instance, if a user tries to enter new records but left some of the fields empty, I will just replace what is already in the DB with the values he/she enters. But if a field is empty, I want to leave what is already in the DB untouched choosing not to replace it with an empty value. Thanks.

I am using C# within VS2010 and the the database is MSSQL.

Comment: If something is empty you dont want to have anything inserted or ?

Comment: which database technology are you using

Comment: Yes. I want a situation, for instance, if a user tries to enter new records but left some of the fields empty, I will just replace what is already in the DB with the values he/she enters. But if a field is empty, I want to leave what is already in the DB untouched choosing not to replace it with an empty value. Thanks.

Comment: "I want to fly across the Atlantic, but I don't want it to take 8 hours"

Comment: Actually, I have almost 30 text-boxes in all the tabs and some combo boxes. Doing that one after the other looks somehow...

Comment: How are your users going to empty a field in the database? How can they remove an existing value?

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: You should provide us with some more information :/ I've an idea how you could do it, but I'd need more info to give you an example. Are you using DataSets? Generic class? etc..

Comment: Codo Pls see my post @Team-Joki below. I have already answered that. marc_s: I am using C# within VS2010 and the the database is MSSQL. Thanks.

Comment: You might get a better response if you edit your question to include the additional information included in comments above or to questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a null for the empty values into the db and use sql like:

Here is an example for Transact SQL for Microsoft SQL Server, using the isnull function, that checks if the first parameter is null and if sets a column to itself (ie not change it).

```
update the_table
set 
 col_x = isnull(@some_value_x, col_x),
 col_7 = isnull(@some_value_y, col_y)
 .
 .
 .
```

in the C# code you could use:

```
string some_value_x = textbox_x.Text.Trim();
if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(some_value_x)) 
       some_value_x = null;
```

Comment: I get this point of checking for nullity in the textbox field before insert operation, but how can I do the "bulk" insert with just few lines of code. Thank you.

Comment: Are the values in the text boxes going to be stored in the same column?

Answer (score 0):

I think the preferred method is to load existing values from the DB into the text boxes and then save them back into the db on the update, so users can blank out a field if they want.  This will simplify your logic and be more consistent with current practices.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
          string s;

          foreach (Control cc in this.Controls)
          {
              if (cc is ComboBox || cc is TextBox)
              {
                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc.Text))
                  {
                      s = cc.Text;
                      //Do something with the value
                  }
              }
```